# jquery ajax beforesend wait before sending

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, timeout

I am trying to use settimeout in the ajaxsetup beforesend function, but what seems to happen is the ajax is sent and the wait function is called after the timeout. I want to stop the requests from sending for the timeout period

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(){
        setTimeout(continueExecution,1000)

        return true;
    }
});
```

Can someone suggest me a way to stop the requests from being sent from ajaxsetup

Comment: "Description: Set default values for future Ajax requests. Its use is not recommended." Just want to notify you

Comment: why would you want to have a delay before request, there may be a better solution if you post your actual reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can return false to cancel ajax request and create new one in setTimeout callback:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(jqXHR, options) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            // null beforeSend to prevent recursive ajax call
            $.ajax($.extend(options, {beforeSend: $.noop}));
        }, 5000);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works, only problem is when I add .done for a ajax request, it does not work, but I can manage without it

Answer (score 2):

you can try this, put the ajax request into setTimout function

```
setTimeout(function(){
  //do the ajax request
}, 2000);
```

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with beforeSend. The reason is setTimeout is async. If you try the code below you'll see that but busy waiting may not be a good idea.

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({
beforeSend: function() {
    var i = 0;

    function testt() {
        i++;
        console.log(i);
        if (i < 10000) {
            testt();
        }
    }
    testt();
    return true;
}
```

});

Comment: Thanks for helping me out, it works, two problems are a) if i remove console.log then the requests are sent right away b) it blocks the ui but other than works just works the way i want. Do you have any fix for those problems?

Comment: I think jcubic's answer will meet your need. Did you try it? I dont have a better solution.